# VSTO Workbook 64 bit excel. Sheet1_Startup does not fire

Tags: excel, 64-bit, vsto, startup

I am attempting to follow the walkthrough to create a simple Document level customization for excel.

**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668197.aspx**

I am running 
- windows 10 (64 bit)
- Excel (64 bit)
- Visual Studio Community 2015 (C#)

The tutorial asks me to enter the C# code:

```
    private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange nr =
            this.Controls.AddNamedRange(this.Range["A2"], "NamedRange1");
        nr.Value2 = "This text was added by using code";
    }
```

It builds and runs fine within the Visual Studio IDE. However, when I open the workbook normally, outside Visual Studio, the range A2 does not get populated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think if you do the part under **Cleaning up the Project** the addin is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. I just needed to publish the solution